# how to query an array of objects in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have an array of objects in laravel that i want to use where query on them so here is my code below :

```
  array:18 [▼
  0 => RoomPricingHistory {#498 ▼
    #fillable: array:19 [▶]
    #connection: "mysql"
    #table: "room_pricing_histories"
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #keyType: "int"
    +incrementing: true
    #with: []
    #withCount: []
    #perPage: 15
    +exists: true
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    #attributes: array:22 [▶]
    #original: array:22 [▼
      "id" => 326
      "accommodation_room_id" => 1
      "net_price" => null
      "sales_price" => 3660000
      "extra_bed_price" => null
      "half_charge_price" => null
      "half_board_price" => null
      "full_board_price" => null
      "foreign_net_price" => null
      "foreign_sales_price" => null
      "foreign_extra_bed_price" => null
      "foreign_half_charge_price" => null
      "foreign_half_board_price" => null
      "foreign_full_board_price" => null
      "operator_id" => 11
      "commission_percent" => null
      "discount_percent" => 5.0
      "from_date" => "2019-05-25 09:00:00"
      "to_date" => "2019-08-30 09:00:00"
      "is_deleted" => 0
      "created_at" => "2019-05-25 09:00:00"
      "updated_at" => "2019-05-25 09:00:00"
    ]
    #changes: []
    #casts: []
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #appends: []
    #dispatchesEvents: []
    #observables: []
    #relations: []
    #touches: []
    +timestamps: true
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  }
  1 => RoomPricingHistory {#506 ▶}
  2 => RoomPricingHistory {#513 ▶}
  3 => RoomPricingHistory {#520 ▶}
  4 => RoomPricingHistory {#527 ▶}
  5 => RoomPricingHistory {#534 ▶}
  6 => RoomPricingHistory {#541 ▶}
  7 => RoomPricingHistory {#548 ▶}
  8 => RoomPricingHistory {#555 ▶}
  9 => RoomPricingHistory {#562 ▶}
  10 => RoomPricingHistory {#569 ▶}
  11 => RoomPricingHistory {#576 ▶}
  12 => RoomPricingHistory {#583 ▶}
  13 => RoomPricingHistory {#590 ▶}
  14 => RoomPricingHistory {#597 ▶}
  15 => RoomPricingHistory {#604 ▶}
  16 => RoomPricingHistory {#611 ▶}
  17 => RoomPricingHistory {#618 ▶}
]
```

so here now for example i have 17 rooms here 5 with of 1, 5 with id of 2 , and 7 with id of 3 in this result and i want to get the last sales_price for each room so i in the end i would have 3 result with room id of 1 -2 -3 and with thier last price . just to mention i sorted them by date before the result

Comment: If you put array into [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/collections), you can filter it with fluent helpers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code for getting last record:

```
    for ($f = 0; $f < count($room_id); $f++) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($dates); $i++) {
            $roomprice[$f] = RoomPricingHistory::
            Where('accommodation_room_id', $room_id[$f])
            ->whereDate('from_date', '<=', $dates[$i])
            ->whereDate('to_date', '>=', $dates[$i])
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

let's say you have the data in the variable called `$collection` then you can execute the following code to filter data:

we first group data by `id` then select the last record.

```
$grouped = $collection->groupBy('id')->last();

$grouped->toArray();
```